# AdonisJs nested relationships

Tags: adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Have try to create and nested relation with adonisjs.

```
Invoice -> hasMany -> InvoiceDetails -> belongsTo -> product
```

This is the Laravel query that works!

```
Invoice::with('invoiceDetails.product')->get();
```

**These are my relations**

***Invoice Model***

```
@hasMany(() => InvoiceDetail,{foreignKey: 'invoice_id'})
public invoiceDetails: HasMany<typeof InvoiceDetail>
```

***InvoiceDetails Model***

```
@belongsTo(() => Product,{foreignKey: 'product_id'})
public product: BelongsTo<typeof Product>
```

***Invoice Controller***

```
const invoice = await Invoice.query().preload('invoiceDetails').where('id', request.param('id')).firstOrFail();
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solutions.but i don't know about the solutions is best.

there is my solutions

```js
 const invoice = await Invoice
  .query()
  .preload('invoiceDetails', (profileQuery) => {
    profileQuery.preload('product')
  })
  .where('id', request.param('id'))
  .firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.